# Problems with Information Security SE sites?

Tags: support

I'm having trouble posting a question to INFOSEC SE. The *Post Question* button is greyed out, and there are no errors or indications I can find with the question:

[image]

In the above image, I am logged into the site even though its lopped off (to show the *Post Question* button).

I wanted to ask about it on Meta INFOSEC SE, but I can't seem to sign-in on that site either:

[image]

Are there any troubles on the INFOSEC SE sites? Or has my account been flagged and this is some sort of purgatory?

Comment: It looks a lot like, for one thing, Javascript isn't loading for you there. Can you check the dev tools and see if there are any errors reported there? I also spy "https" in the address bar. We don't fully support SSL just yet. Are you having any problems posting a question over a normal HTTP connection?

Comment: Ah, OK. It looks like the mixed content being served is causing the problems. EFF's HTTPS Everywhere had flagged an additional SE site and at least two partner sites. The odd thing is I have *not* had problems with INFOSEC SE in the past.

Comment: It looks like Firefox 29.0.1 was released [about three weeks ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Firefox#Version_29). Apparently, something changed between Firefox or HTTPS Everywhere and it uncovered security usability some issues.

Answer (score 2):

The solution: per the comments, the OP turned off [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere).